# Learning Spanish

Tags: vocabulario, gramática, pronunciación

Can you give me some tips how I can start learning Spanish ?
A way where I don't have to drill vocabularies and grammar.

When I learned languages at school I was always able to read and write, but the important things of a language: the speaking and understanding wasn't that well developed.

So this time I want to learn Spanish in a way, that will develop the important skills of languages. And in an easy way, that isn't boring and makes fun.

I want to be able to speak and understand (listening).

Do you have some tips how I can start learning ?

*or*

How were your experiences with learning foreign languages and how did it work best for you ?

Comment: What's with changing the question?

Comment: ¡Hola! ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Can you please make clear what is your question so we can help you? What was the reason to edit and remove it?

Comment: Welcome to our site! It's really hard to identify an actual question here. There's also a lot of background information that isn't really relevant (that you learned French in school, for instance).  Can you try to focus your question?

Comment: Thank you for improving your question. However, it's still too broad to be a good fit for this site, as it is more of a discussion question than an objective question with a specific answer. There are many ways to learn a foreign language which don't involve vocab and grammar drills, which have varying degrees of usefulness depending on your context and learning goals.

Comment: At least once or twice a week do a language exchange, where you practice talking with a native speaker (this can be done in skype, using websites like italki to find partners, if you don't want spend time with them in english you can also pay ~5-15$/hour to talk just in spanish with them). Movies in spanish, I feel requires a bit more advantaced level, even with subtitles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Duolingo (web/Android/iOS). I'm learning French with it and I find it quite useful.

Comment: Duolingo FTW! It makes Rosetta Stone look like an old rock.

Comment: Does it also work for Spanish ?
Edit:
Yes it works when you choose that you're english. I will test it out. thx

Comment: Really nice. It works very good. Même quand ce n'existe pas dans ma langue (allemand) pour apprendre espagnol. Good luck with your french and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions.

One of the things that I did when I was learning Spanish which was fun and helped a lot was to watch Spanish movies with English subtitles. It helped me to pick up common phrases and lots of vocabulary.

My second suggestion is to find some Spanish language meetups or groups in your area and go to them. There are different kinds- I found the best ones are where it is just a group where you are encouraged to speak Spanish with each other. There are other ones where you sit in a circle and take turns to speak, but I find those intimidating and unhelpful. Just like the movies, it helps pick up common phrases and vocabulary and is a great way to meet other people who are learning Spanish and native speakers too. www.meetup.com is a great resource for finding groups and meetups.